# User_save is very slow for no apparent reason

Tags: 7, users

As you could see on picture, saving data for users is very slow. Queries run fast, but for some reason it takes up to 2 minutes to save user data. The same happens with logging in.

What is more strange, I have DB versions of this site and have a previous version where this works normally and all of a sudden this started to happen.

- I checked errors in log
- Disabled modules
- Cache reseting
- Exported DB tables from working DB (user, user_roles, variables) to non working
- Checked for missing modules
- Tried older version of drupal (7.33).
- Disabled some custom code modules

Tried everything I could come up, but still user_save is slow like on image and no errors or warnings appear. Really don't have a clue anymore what could be wrong, something in DB level must been wrong, not sure what to try anymore and where to look?

[image]

Comment: XHProf would prove to be quite useful here in identifying script responsible for affecting the performance or whether it's the database.

Comment: Thanx on suggestion. I am planning to do that tomorrow, hopeing it will help. Something in DB is making system hang, but queries are fast so must be some script that hangs because of particular data in DB. As I tested the same code base with different DB and DB is the one making the differnce.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, well the reason. I had a in a module
hook_user_update()

that has a CURL that connects to remote site and beacuse of it took much time to save, well to connect and then to save.  Need a way to make this CURL connection not affect the user save.